# Unable to turn off automatic margins by termcap in Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, margins, terminfo, termcap

I need to turn automatic margins off according the following statement from Screen's manual in my Mac

> If  your  terminal is a "true"
>   auto-margin terminal (it doesn't allow
>   the last position on the screen
>          to be updated without scrolling the screen) consider using a version
>   of your terminal's termcap  that
>          has  automatic  margins  turned off.

**How can you turn automatic margins off by your terminal's termcap?**

Comment: Did you actually encounter any problems, or are you merely being cautious about what the `screen` manual says? I haven't noticed any problems using `screen` with Terminal, using default settings. Are you using the Terminal application or some other terminal program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), this sequence should do what was asked:

```
CSI ? 7 l
```

That is,

```
printf '\033[?7l'
```

The **7** is documented as

```
        Ps = 7  -> Wraparound Mode (DECAWM).
```

and the final character **`l`** (lowercase L) denotes this as a *reset* rather than a *set* control.

For whatever reason, the terminfo name for this is more obscure: "automatic margins".  These terminfo capabilities deal with the feature (see [terminfo(5)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html)):

```
   auto_right_margin             am         am        terminal has auto‐
                                                      matic margins
   enter_am_mode                 smam       SA        turn on automatic
                                                      margins
   exit_am_mode                  rmam       RA        turn off automatic
                                                      margins
```

Interestingly, the [vt100-nam](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-vt100nam) terminal description in ncurses (which apparently no one uses) initializes the terminal to **use** automargins margins using this string:

```
rs2=\E>\E[?3l\E[?4l\E[?5l\E[?7h\E[?8h,
```

(the `\E[?7h` sets it), and asserts that the terminal does not use automatic margins by cancelling **`am`**.  It also has the terminfo capabilities `rmam` and `smam`.  So you could do this to prove that it works:

```
tput rmam
stty columns 999
ps -efwwwwwl
```

and (for the ordinary user) see the `ps` listing nicely truncated against the right margin of the terminal window.

The other variants vt220-nam and vt320-nam appear correct...

By the way, for **Mac**, you would use the **terminfo** names such as **`rmcup`** rather than the **termcap** **`RA`**, because OSX uses ncurses' tput (terminfo) rather than the BSD variant.

Further reading:

- [**`tput`**,  **`reset`**  -  initialize  a  terminal or query terminfo
     database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html)
- [history section for **`tput`**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h2-HISTORY)
- [history section for **`tset`**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h2-HISTORY)

Occasionally someone asks about suppressing automargins because they suppose that terminals can pan/scroll left/right to show the information which was not wrapped to a new line.   Terminals which do this are rare, and OSX Terminal is not one of *those*.  It behaves like a subset of xterm, which itself emulates the series of DEC terminals vt52/vt100/vt220/etc.  In **this** question, OP is concerned/confused about this paragraph from the `screen` manual:

> If your terminal is a "true" auto-margin terminal (it doesn't allow the
>   **last position on the screen** to be updated without scrolling the screen)
>   consider  using a version of your terminal's termcap that has automatic
>   margins turned off. This will ensure an accurate and optimal update  of
>   the  screen  in all circumstances. Most terminals nowadays have "magic"
>   margins (automatic margins plus usable last column). This is the  VT100
>   style  type  and  perfectly  suited for screen.  If all you've got is a
>   "true" auto-margin terminal screen will  be  content  to  use  it,  but
>   updating  a  character put into the last position on the screen may not
>   be possible until the screen scrolls or the character is moved  into  a
>   safe position in some other way. This delay can be shortened by using a
>   terminal with insert-character capability.

That **last position on the screen** refers to the lower-right corner of the terminal.  In the normal case, if your cursor is on the lower-right corner and you print a character, you would expect the display to scroll up by one line and show the character on the next line.  Also (because terminals can be implemented in different ways), some *could* scroll up when you print a character in the **last position**.  The VT100 does not do this.  Not only does it not scroll up in that case, but it ignores non-printing characters while **on** the margin (see xterm FAQ [That description of wrapping is odd, say more?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#vt100_wrapping)).  There is a terminfo flag `xenl` which is set to show when the terminal does this special behavior.  About a third of the terminal descriptions in the terminal database have this flag.  While most of those are for terminals which you likely will never encounter, keep in mind that the advice in the manual page was written back in an era when those other terminals were as likely to be found as a VT100-lookalike.  The early change-history  for screen is poor, but the text was in screen's second posting to Usenet in 1992.  The initial posting in 1987 said something similar:

> *Screen*
>   never writes in the last position of the screen, unless the boolean
>   capability **`LP`** is found in the termcap entry of the terminal.
>   Usually,
>   *screen*
>   cannot predict whether or not a particular terminal scrolls when
>   a character is written in the last column of the last line;
>   **`LP`** indicates that it is safe to write in this position.
>   Note that the **`LP`** capability is independent of **`am`** (automatic
>   margins); for certain terminals, such as the VT100, it is reasonable
>   to set **`am`** as well as **`LP`** in the corresponding termcap entry
>   (the VT100 does not move the cursor when a character is written in
>   the last column of each line).

The later wording reflects the fact that the `terminfo` system was prevalent, and the name **`LP`** was not termcap name chosen for corresponding with `xenl` (it is **`xn`**).

The point of all of this is that `screen` attempts to convert between programs writing to different terminal types and make them all appear like one type of terminal — which means that it tries to put text on the terminal's display in all of the locations.  The lower-right corner is a problem because some terminals would scroll up, spoiling the attempt to write there.  As a workaround, some terminals provided an alternative:

- using a different mode (insert),
- put the cursor on the **next to last position** of the display,
- write characters to fill in, *pushing* a character into the last position, and
- turn insert-mode off once it is done (otherwise a nuisance).

About two thirds of the descriptions in the terminal database have the capability to do this insert-mode (**`smir`**).  That still was not perfect, but it certainly was worth mentioning in 1992.  About a quarter implement a similar similar feature **`ich1`**.  Some implement both (and **`vi`** could get confused by those, by trying to do both methods).

VT100-lookalikes provide a third way to write that last position; `screen` checks for and uses whatever is there.

Comment: The screen manpage is talking about (the lack of) VT100-style `xenl` when it's talking about "true auto-margin terminals", this might be worth adding to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Most terminal emulators, including the mac default terminal, are not "true auto-margin terminals" in the sense being discussed here - they emulate a vt100-series terminal, which had "smart" wraparound. You can check by running `cat` and typing to the end of the last line - after you type the last character, the cursor remains at the end of the line (highlighting the character you just typed) until you type another character.

The only consequence of a 'true auto-margin terminal' is that a character cannot be displayed in the lower right hand corner (though some programs are able to work around that by shifting a character into place with `ich`/`ich1`)

Comment: It would be really great to get .gif animation about the event. - - I am now in Debian 8.5 so I should be able to test it.

Comment: @Masi you can also install `tack` and run the test for the `xenl` capability which checks the type of automatic margin.

Comment: Can you show the workflow here what you mean, please.

Comment: @Masi I don't understand what part's not clear or what you mean by workflow.

Comment: Workflow is about how you do the things which you propose in your own test system. I am now outside of Mac so I cannot test them. Normally, I include all outputs of all relevant commands from the start to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're looking to set the autowrap feature to NO using terminfo database.  If so I believe you can use the -nam flag to turn it off - something like vt100-nam should do it. You can also check by looking at the man pages for terminfo.

If this solves your question, mark this up.  (^_^)  If not... well comment back and I'll check again for you.  Cheers!

Update:  There's also a shortcut that may apply to you to toggle the wrap off and on.  Check out the shortcut sheet [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/985314/Screen-VT100ANSI-Terminal-Emulator-Cheat-Sheet-Default-Keyboard-Shortcuts). And additional information for Screen can be found [here](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/1/screen) (search for wrap).  You can also check [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Text-Terminal-HOWTO/) on how to use setterm (section 17.14 Changing the Terminal Settings).  Also check [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/Screen/screenrc_examples.shtml) for examples of changing settings.

Good luck again.  (^_^)

Comment: Yay!  I'm glad I could help.  Was this the information you were looking for?  (^_^)

Comment: @Kevin: Thank you for your help! The info convinced me that I could not improve Mac's default terminal over the limits. Finally, I moved to iTerm which can update its screen much often.

Comment: @Masi:  Hey no problem, I'm glad I could help!  Good luck!  (^_^)